# Unable to create table using PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a table using PDO my connection is fine as i just tested it with try catch block. But i am unable to create any table in my DB

```
function loadData($table)
{

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anlyatics_db", "root", "");
$query = "CREATE TABLE if not exists $table); ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if ($stmt)
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? A blank screen? What happens when this code runs? Is there anything in `$stmt->ErrorInfo()`?

Comment: havnet check that, let me get a hold on to that

Comment: Is your DB name spelled correctly?

Comment: what does `$table` contain?

Comment: yes DB named is spelled correctly as i mentioned in my post there is no Error and i tested it in Try catch block didnt got any exception while creating connection

Comment: Can we see how you are calling `loadData`

Comment: @oezi it contains name for the table e.g at the moment it has CDM_2011

Comment: please provide $table + the exact error you get.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: i am using core php so i am just calling function.

Comment: @Jeroen: getting no error.

Comment: PS: your db name is "anlyatics_db", it isn't by any chance a typo and suppose to be analytics_db? Sorry if it sounds like a silly answer, not intended to be.

Comment: @Jeroen: nah it isnt typo

Comment: I wonder if this question ever be closed (as it ought to be)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: is there any common sense to close a question clearly when some 1 is missing some thing? that should be  understood, which in my case is that table cant be created without column names.

Comment: Yes sure. Frankly, it's not a question at all.

Comment: i found my answer, i hope you know what was missing in my case,(i personally discourage trolls i hope you wont mind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment:

" it contains name for the table e.g at the moment it has CDM_2011"

I would say you need to add columns to your create statement. I don't think you can have a create statement without column definitions.

Comment: yeah looks legit need to have look at it

Comment: just to see if this is the issue, try this: CREATE TABLE if not exists $table (id int);

Comment: oh right: after $table you have a closing bracket, you nowhere have an opening bracket either

Comment: Marking it correct as table cant be created without column definiton and marking your post correct is for the face you point it out 1st.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the `CREATE` right??
See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html) for a MySQL User management?

For my part, I'm not sure that create table from PHP is safe!...

To retrieve the error, use

```
$conn->errorInfo();
```

[PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

**EDIT**

Have you tried to put at least 1 column? As you can see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), MySQL `CREATE` statement needs 1 column...

Comment: the solution you mentioned returns Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: Ok so in the array : `([0]=>00000, [1]=>, [2]=>))` the first mean : SQLSTATE, and it is 0... So no error returned.